# How to fix value is not a member of specific trait with instance of this specific trait?

Tags: scala, traits, member, extends

I have a trait `Observer` which I implemented according to Erich Gamma's Design Pattern.

```
trait Observer {
  def update: Unit
}

class Observable {
  var subscribers: Vector[Observer] = Vector()

  def add(s: Observer): Unit = subscribers = subscribers :+ s

  def remove(s: Observer): Unit = subscribers = subscribers.filterNot(o => o == s)

  def notifyObserver: Unit = subscribers.foreach(o => o.update)
}
```

This Observer keeps an eye on one of my controllers and signals every change made inside of it.

When I try to create an instance of that trait to particular test it inside for example my testing class for the `Controller` (which extends Observable) ...

```
class ControllerSpec extends AnyWordSpec with Matchers {
  "A controller" when {
    "observed by an Observer" should {
      val desk = new Desk(3)
      val controller = new Controller(desk)

      // new instance of trait observer
      val observer = new Observer {
        var updated: Boolean = false

        def isUpdated: Boolean = updated

        override def update: Unit = {
          updated = true; updated
        }

      }
      controller.add(observer)
      "notify its Observer after creation" in {
        controller.createEmptyDesk(3)
        observer.updated should be(true) // fails
        controller.desk.size should be(3)
      }
...
...
...
```

...I get the following problem by the compiler.

```
value updated is not a member of ***.util.Observer - did you mean observer.update?
observer.updated should be(true)
```

For some reason the compiler does not accept that I created a new instance of that trait and extended it with new values or rather methods. Instead it redirects me to the trait directly in which such values or methods are not defined nor mentioned.

Thought this would be possible in order to test my classes properly. Anyone has an idea of what is going on or what I have been maybe missing out?

I am kind of new to Scala and currently using the new Scala-3. Before that, I came in touch with the Version 2 and never had a problem like this.

Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Why not put the `updated` variable outside of the observer if you need to access it from outside?

Comment: Also note that this has nothing to do with Scala 3, the same would happen in Scala 2.

Comment: The problem is that `observer ` is of type `Observer` which doesn't have any method `updated` defined, thus it fails. You may refine the type, use reflection, create a class which exposes that method instead of using a anonymous class, use an object, etc.